# How come my python script can't properly import installed libraries on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, windows-10

I have python installed in the default location C:\Python27.

I installed pip and was able to install libraries

The libraries got installed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

When I run the python interpreter I can successfully import the libraries but when I run a python file it gives an Import Error.

I was wondering how to fix this.

Comment: Can you post the code in the python file as well?

Comment: can you give a short example code and the exact error?

Comment: By the way, any new Python development should use Python3. Python also includes pip for all latest releases, so you installed it separately?

Comment: @cricket_007 I use Python 2.7 because I use the speech recognition library and from what I have found its only python2.7. my script  {from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs} now I know all the code works because I have run on both unix and linux just trying to make it work on windows. The pip installs work just not when called from a script. All code can be found here https://github.com/SavageCoder77/MARVIN_2.0. When I installed python it didn't install pip so i ran the get-pip.py file to get pip

Comment: SpeechRecognition supports Python 3.3+ https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/ and unless you downloaded Python older than 2.7.9, than the documentation specifically says pip is included

Comment: Found the main problem I had installed the 32 bit version in case any libraries I used in the future were 32 bit. the 64 bit version comes with everything including pip. But the installs are still not found